# Firebase Phone auth by call

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Suppose I need to verify users by Firebase phone authentication.
But somehow, user is not getting otp sms. So does firebase gives the option to get the OTP by receiving call?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Authentication to sign in a new user by sending an SMS message to his phone, he would then receive a verification code to his phone number via SMS which would then allow him to sign in if the code is correct. However it's not possible yet to give the user his verification code via a voice call. Maybe they will do it in a future release ? It would be great indeed !